# error while parsing - Encountered: <EOF> after

Tags: apache-velocity

I am parsing a simple template and getting this error:

```
org.apache.velocity.loader - ResourceManager: 
parse exception: Lexical error,   Encountered: <EOF> after : "" at
```

If I add an empty line at the end of the template then I don't have the same issue,
And parse is done correctly.

Is it a parser bug?

update velocity version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: what's your velocity version?

Comment: updated with velocity version